# Core ML model including custom layer is slow

Tags: caffe, coreml

I have changed the coremltools(caffe to Core ML, https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.caffe.convert.html#coremltools.converters.caffe.convert) and added custom layer into Core ML model. But compare to non-custom caffe layer Core ML model, Core ML(including custom layer) speed is slower. I have found that coremlc compile mlmodel, and fuse some layer， for example, conv+bn+scale, conv+relu. 
[conv+bn+scale fused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozQlE.jpg)[conv+relu fused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6llW.jpg)

I used instrument(time profiler) to perform the Core ML model, and found there was more functions(time-consumed) (custom layer Core ML model) than (non-custom layer Core ML model), everyone know why? 
[Core ML model time profiler on CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SDZ7.jpg)

Comment: What does your custom layer do?

Comment: custom layer include pooling layer && upsample layer. These layer just  count a few time of forward. I found the more layers of model, the more times(extra restore_layers_if_wiper/MLNeuralNetworkEngine resetSizes:error)